# How can I smoothly stretch and shrink a revolving line arc?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations, spinner

Google's Material Design spinners shring and stretch while rotating:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have found the following SVG spinner which implements it pretty well here: https://codepen.io/svnt/pen/qraaRN.

HTML:

```
<svg class="spinner" viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle class="path" cx="25" cy="25" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="5"></circle></svg>
```

CSS:

```
/* SVG spinner icon animation */
.spinner {
  -webkit-animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
          animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.spinner .path {
  stroke: #cccccc;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  -webkit-animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
          animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 150;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 90, 150;
    stroke-dashoffset: -35;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 90, 150;
    stroke-dashoffset: -124;
  }
}
@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 150;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 90, 150;
    stroke-dashoffset: -35;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 90, 150;
    stroke-dashoffset: -124;
  }
}
```

The thing is, the `@keyframes` animation uses `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` which seem to run on the main UI thread as if I do some tasks with JavaScript while the animation is running, the spinner looses its smoothness and becomes jerky.

The rotation (via `transform`) works pretty well, and I know it runs off the UI thread, so even if I perform some JS task the rotation will be smooth while animating.

Of course, I can just implement a rotating spinner without the stretch/shrink stuff, but I was wondering if someone of you knows how to make such animations always look smooth. Is there a way to stretch and shrink the spinner using `transform` while it rotates?

Hope I was clear. Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate this using different elements where the idea is to hide the first one using the other. The only drawback is the transparency.

Here is an example where you can adjust the different values to get the needed animation. Used CSS variable for simplicity but it's not mandatory.

```css
.loading {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:fixed;
  top:calc(50% - 25px);
  left:calc(50% - 25px);
  border-radius:50%;
  border:5px solid blue;
  animation:load 2s linear  infinite;
}
.loading:before,
.loading:after,
.loading span:before,
.loading span:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-6px;
  left:-6px;
  right:-6px;
  bottom:-6px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:7px solid transparent;
  border-left-color:white;
  animation:hide 1.2s infinite;
}
.loading span:before {
  --r:90deg;
}
.loading span:after {
  --r:180deg;
}
.loading:before {
  --r:260deg; /* a little less than 270deg to keep some border visible */
}

@keyframes load {
  to {
   transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  50% {
   transform:rotate(var(--r,0deg));
  }
  100% {
   transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

With transparency you can create the border using 4 elements that you rotate to make them above each other and shrink the overal shape. Basically the opposite logic of the first code (we change what was blue with transparent and what was white with blue)

The only drawback is that you cannot shrink less that the length of one side

```css
.loading {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:fixed;
  top:calc(50% - 25px);
  left:calc(50% - 25px);
  animation:load 2s linear  infinite;
}
.loading:before,
.loading:after,
.loading span:before,
.loading span:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:5px solid transparent;
  border-left-color:blue;
  animation:hide 1.2s infinite;
}
.loading span:before {
  --r:90deg;
}
.loading span:after {
  --r:180deg;
}
.loading:before {
  --r:200deg;
}


@keyframes load {
  to {
   transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  50% {
   transform:rotate(var(--r,0deg));
  }
  100% {
   transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}

body {
 background:linear-gradient(to right,pink,orange);
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

---

To better understand what is happening in both codes, remove the main rotation and use different color for borders

```css
.loading {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  position:fixed;
  top:calc(50% - 25px);
  left:calc(50% - 25px);
 /* animation:load 2s linear  infinite;*/
}
.loading:before,
.loading:after,
.loading span:before,
.loading span:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:-0;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:5px solid transparent;
  border-left-color:blue;
  animation:hide 4s infinite;
}
.loading span:before {
  --r:90deg;
    border-left-color:red;
}
.loading span:after {
  --r:180deg;
    border-left-color:green;
}
.loading:before {
  --r:260deg;
    border-left-color:yellow;
}


@keyframes load {
  to {
   transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes hide {
  50% {
   transform:rotate(var(--r,0deg));
  }
  100% {
   transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}

body {
 background:linear-gradient(to right,pink,orange);
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you for the quick answer. It is a bit tricky to me to understand how those pseudo elements work. Anyway, do you think is there a way to avoid using white borders for them?

Comment: @tonix it's easy to understand, make each one with a different color in its border and you will see how they are moving ... actually I don't think there is a way without the white coloration but I will keep thinking about ;)

Comment: @tonix found another idea, still with a small drawback but with transparency ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your edit and explanation! Now I think I understood how it works. Correct me if I am wrong: at a given time all the pseudo-elements have a rotation of `0` degree. At `50%` of the `hide` animation, the `blue` border stays where it was, the while the `red`, `green` and `yellow` transition from `0` to `90`, `180` and `260` degrees, respectively in `2 seconds`. Finally, from `50%` to `100%` of the animation, all the bars transition to `360` degrees within `2 other seconds`, and at this point (after `4 seconds`) the animation restarts. Did I get it?

Comment: @tonix exactly, at 50% they will no more overlap and you will have the stretch effect then at 0% and 100% they are overlapping and since 0deg is equal to 360deg, you have a continuous animation and then you rotate all this using the animation on the main container.